# {$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE} in 64 bit delphi application

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, 64-bit

Does `{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}` have any effects on 64-bit delphi applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has no effect at all. All 64 bit processes are automatically decreed to be large address aware.

Comment: Not according to MSDN: [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases): "*User-mode virtual address space for each 64-bit process: Limit in 64-bit Windows: With IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE set (default): 7-128 TB (depending on CPU and OS version). **2 GB with IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE cleared***" I wonder if that is really true, or if it is a typo?